# Wordpress ACF repeater get info SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

Need a little help here please, Im trying to get info from wp_postmeta assigned to a id_post from a plugin called ACF, this is the structure:

```
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
| meta_id    | post_id  | meta_key                                | meta_value                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  134704    | 462      | rates_group_0_rates_group_title         | Center/East Programs        |
|  134705    | 462      | rates_group_1_rates_group_title         | South/Center Programs       |
|  134706    | 462      | rates_group_2_rates_group_title         | East Center Program         |
|  134707    | 462      | rates_group_3_rates_group_title         | South/East Center Programs  |
|  134708    | 462      | rates_group_0_rates_group_second_title  | 4 Day Itineraries           |
|  134709    | 462      | rates_group_1_rates_group_second_title  | 5 Day Itineraries           |
|  134710    | 462      | rates_group_2_rates_group_second_title  | 6 Day Itineraries           |
|  134711    | 462      | rates_group_3_rates_group_second_title  | 7 Day Itineraries           |
+------------+----------+-----------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

and this is my sql query:

```
SELECT
  post.ID,
    post.post_title,
    meta1.meta_value,
  meta2.meta_value
FROM wp_posts post
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta1 ON meta1.post_id = post.ID AND meta1.meta_key like 'rates_group_%_rates_group_title'
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta meta2 ON meta2.post_id = post.ID AND meta2.meta_key like 'rates_group_%_rates_group_second_title'
WHERE
  post.post_type = 'portfolio'
AND post.ID=462
GROUP BY meta1.meta_key
```

This is the result:

```
+--------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID     | post_title | meta_value                  | meta_value1              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  462   | Title      | Center/East Programs        | 4 Day Itineraries        |
|  462   | Title      | South/Center Programs       | 4 Day Itineraries        |
|  462   | Title      | East Center Program         | 4 Day Itineraries        |
|  462   | Title      | South/East Center Programs  | 4 Day Itineraries        |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

and this is the expected result:

```
+--------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
| ID     | post_title | meta_value                  | meta_value1              |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  462   | Title      | Center/East Programs        | 4 Day Itineraries        |
|  462   | Title      | South/Center Programs       | 5 Day Itineraries        |
|  462   | Title      | East Center Program         | 6 Day Itineraries        |
|  462   | Title      | South/East Center Programs  | 7 Day Itineraries        |
+--------+------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

This is an example using 2 fields `rates_group_title` and `rates_group_second_title` but there should be more fields but the result should always show in 4 rows.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you use the default ACF get metafunctions -https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/.?

Comment: @YuxelYuseinov im working in a custom platform outside WP, that's why.

Comment: What happens or what's the result when you remove `GROUP BY meta1.meta_key` ?

Comment: @SallyCJ I get 16 results instead of 4

Comment: You can use `UNION`, but you'll get double the expected rows.. so in the case of the example in your question, you'd get 8 rows [like these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBEh9.jpg) - the first 4 for the `rates_group_%_rates_group_title` meta, and the other 4 for the `rates_group_%_rates_group_second_title` meta. So if you have more fields (like `4`), then you'd get `4 * 4 = 16` rows.

Comment: @SallyCJ tx for ur answer, but im looking a way to only print 4 rows with the info so I can use foreach function.

Comment: I understand. I wouldn't use `UNION`.. but I'm not positive if you could simply use the `INNER JOIN`, `JOIN`, etc. in order to achieve just 4 rows.. all the best, though. 